# TabNavigator within TabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Using react-native and react-navigation, how can I make one of my Tabs an additional `TabNavigator`, but in a way that it covers up the existing tabs?

Following is the general outline of a navigator configuration I'd like. 
However, The "AddNavigator" shows up as tabs on top of my existing tabs. But I'd like them to cover up those tabs.

```js
export const AddNavigator = TabNavigator({
  AddPhoto: { screen: AddPhoto },
  AddText: { screen: AddText },
}, { mode: 'modal', headerMode: 'none' });

export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  TabHome: { screen: TabHome },
  TabAdd: { screen: AddNavigator },
  TabProfile: { screen: TabProfile }
});

export const Root = StackNavigator({
  SplashScreen: { screen: SplashScreen },
  LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
  SignupScreen: { screen: SignupScreen },

  Tabs: { screen: Tabs },

}, { mode: 'modal', headerMode: 'none' });
```

As a reference, consider the Instagram app.
When you click the tab in the middle (to add a photo), you get an additional tab navigator asking to choose "Gallery, Photo, or Video"
[Screenshot](https://9to5google.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/instagram-android-7-0.png)

Answer (score 1):

To simulate your reference of instagram, you can do this:

```js
export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    TabHome: { screen: TabHome },
    TabAdd: {
        screen: AddNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarVisible: false
        }
    },
    TabProfile: { screen: TabProfile }
});
```

[image]